# Bad parameters format when using oauth-js

Tags: angularjs, oauth

my code on angular, and in $scope function I using oauth-js.

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function () {
    OAuth.initialize('my key');
    OAuth.popup('facebook').done(function (result) {
        result.me().done(function (me) {
            console.log('Your name is ' + me.name)
        });
    }).fail(function (err) {
        $log.info(err);
    });
};
```

and error :

```
Error: Bad parameters format
    at Object.sendCallback (oauth.min.js:1)
    at n (oauth.min.js:1)
```

how can i fix it.